# How to set Express.Request.user type from optional User to required User for authorized routes

Tags: typescript, express, passport.js

I'm writing a Express + Typescript server. I'm using passport js to authenticate the routes I'm defining. However, one annoying thing is `Express.Request.user` is `Express.User | undefined`. So, pretty much in every protected handler, I have to check if request is truthy just to make typescript happy.

```js
app.get(
    '/authenticated',
    authPassport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
        if(!req.user) throw new Error();
        console.log(req.user.email)
        res.send('you are authenticated')
    }
)
```

Is there a way to change the type of the `req.user` to have definite value `User`?

Answer (score 0):

if it's typed in ts, you could create your own interface,
and declare an interface for `req.user` value

example:

```html
export interface IUserCredential {
  email: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
}
```

`req.user = user as IUserCredential;`